# travis.ci change sqlite3 version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, travis-ci

I need to change the version of the environment I'm building tests off of.

All tests are passing locally, but a few fail on the travis build. I've found that this is because the version of sqlite3 on travis is 3.7.9 which does not support multiline insert. Version 3.7.11 of sqlite 3 does that and I'm looking for a way to upgrade that in my build.

Here is the failed build with current sqlite3 version of the travis build env.
https://travis-ci.org/cmu-is-projects/ferry/jobs/47168022

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by the pull request https://github.com/cmu-is-projects/ferry/pull/72.

See https://github.com/cmu-is-projects/ferry/blob/master/.travis.yml for more details on the build.

Comment: You should accept your own answer if you found the solution to your problem!